# i got a problem when while sending emails from python , some emails get received but for a specific emails it wont it show the following error

Tags: python

the error is :'utf8' is an invalid keyword argument for Compat32

im trying to get Excel sheet that content emails and send emails to them from my gmail account the problem is most of the emails send successfully but when it reach a specific email it shows that error, btw im using tkinter as GUI 
the email content is (email body uploaded by .txt, pdf file, the Excel sheet that i mentioned before)

```py
def main():
    global frame4
    frame2.place_forget()
    frame4 = Frame(root,borderwidth=5, relief=RIDGE)
    frame4.place(x=0,y=160,width=400,height = 290)
    frame3 = Frame(frame4,borderwidth=1)
    frame3.place(x=0,y=0,width=390,height = 200)
    Exit = Button(frame4, text="Exit",bd = 3, command=ask_quit)
    Exit.place(x=300, y=240, width=80, height=30)
    def go():
        frame4.destroy()
        getall()
    Back = Button(frame4, text="Back",bd = 3, command=go)
    Back.place(x=20, y=240, width=80, height=30)
    list = Listbox(frame3, height=50, width=60)
    scroll = Scrollbar(frame3, command=list.yview)
    list.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
    list.pack(side=LEFT)
    list.update()
    scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    progress = ttk.Progressbar(frame4, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=380, mode='determinate')
    progress.place(x= 10, y= 205,width =370,height =13)
    emails = get_contacts()  # read contacts
    r = len(emails)

    def check():
        if r == 0:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "No email were found, Upload another Excel file")
            frame4.place_forget()
            getall()
        else:
            return
    check()

    message_template = read_template(text_path)
    MY_ADDRESS = email2.get()
    PASSWORD = password.get()
    subject = subject1.get()
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.ehlo()
    s.login(MY_ADDRESS, PASSWORD)
    g = 0
    progress['maximum'] = 100

    for email in emails:

        msg = MIMEMultipart()  # create a message
        message = message_template
        msg['From'] = MY_ADDRESS
        msg['To'] = email
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        filename = pdf_path
        fo = open(filename, "rb")
        attach = MIMEApplication(fo.read(), _subtype="ppt")
        encoders.encode_base64(attach)
        fo.close()
        lastnamepath = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(filename))
        attach.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=lastnamepath)
        msg.attach(MIMEText(message,'plain'))
        msg.attach(attach)
        list.insert(END, email)
        list.update()
        g+=(100/r)
        progress['value'] = g
        frame4.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(0.5)

        s.send_message(msg)
        #s.sendmail(MY_ADDRESS,msg)
        if progress['value'] == 100:
            done = Label(frame4, text= "Done")
            done.place(x=300, y=220, width=80, height=20)

        del msg
   s.close()
```

Comment: What error does it show? You have not provided much clarity in your question. A reedit may improve your prospects of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: sorry its my first time asking here, the error is 
TypeError: 'utf8' is an invalid keyword argument for Compat32

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem and what you did try before posting. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every body for helping me , i already find the problem, the main problem was some of the email show with (\xa0) in front of some emails so the solution:

```
    email = unidecode.unidecode(email)
```